# "--scale 2x2" in xrandr causes the monitor to not display anything

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr, display-resolution

I've got a 4k external main monitor and I'm trying to connect a 1680x1050 external monitor to the left of it.

I've tried using:

```
 xrandr --output HDMI-0 --scale 2x2 --pos 0x0 --fb 7200x2160 --output DP-4 --pos 3360x0
```

which seems like it should work, and when I look at what the computer thinks is going on in nvidia-settings it correctly displays a 3200x2160 monitor to the left of my 4k one.

However on my external monitor just shows black with a flickering line at the top of it.

The only way I can correct this is to reset the scaling back to 1x1 at which point the image returns (while maintaining the X-server size. This means there's just deadspace that I have to scroll through to get between my monitors).

So I think the problem is specifically to do with the 2x2 scaling in xrandr. I'm not sure what to do?

The computer is running 14.04 and has a nvidia GTX960 in it with the recommended driver (352.63)

Here's my xrandr output:

```
  Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 7200 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
  DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  HDMI-0 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
     1680x1050      59.9*+   60.0  
     1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
     1280x960       60.0  
     1152x864       75.0  
     1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
     800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
     640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
  DP-4 connected primary 3840x2160+3360+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
     3840x2160      60.0*+   30.0  
     2560x1440      60.0  
     2048x1280      60.0  
     1920x1200      59.9  
     1920x1080      60.0     60.0     59.9     50.0     24.0     60.0     50.0  
     1600x1200      60.0  
     1600x900       60.0  
     1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
     1280x720       60.0     59.9     50.0  
     1152x864       75.0  
     1024x768       75.0     60.0  
     800x600        75.0     60.3  
     720x576        50.0     50.1  
     720x480        59.9     60.1  
     640x480        75.0     59.9     59.9
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It seems to be working up to scale 1.71x1.71. Everything bigger causes smaller display to go blank

Comment: Unfortunately I never managed to fix this. I was trying to run two monitors, one with scaling and one without. If you're just trying to run  at 2x scaling then it's very easy with Cinammon. I believe there's a way to get Unity to do it too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just wanted to add that this is something I've been fighting with for a long time, and each time I just gave up - until I decided to figure it out once and for all. The solution below works for me, hope it does for you as well.

tl;dr: Configure `ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On`

### Background

Some of this is also in hopes of providing more keywords in case someone with a similar problem ends up looking for the solution.

My setup is:

- ThinkPad P50 with a built-in 4K display at 3840×2160 (primary)
- An external monitor as a secondary display - Dell U2412M - 1920×1200

I use Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS.

When I plug in the monitor via a HDMI cable + a HDMI-to-DVI converter (as the monitor doesn't have an HDMI input), everything was too large. Various articles online suggested using `xrandr` to configure `--scale 2x2` on that display, which resulted in it being almost completely black, with only a thin line visible on top.

I bumped into this question and while the `2x2.001` scaling solution enabled the monitor to actually display stuff, it also added an extra pixel below the X screen which resulted in slight up/down scrolling when the cursors reaches the top/bottom of the screen.

After a lot of Googling, much of which yielded problems and no solutions, I stumbled upon this: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/891207/-355-11-358-09-viewportin-on-2nd-monitor-results-in-garbled-display-for-values-over-3211x1800

So to test it out, I configured this using the following commands - assume `xrandr` hasn't been configured with scaling yet.

```
$ nvidia-settings -q CurrentMetaMode

  Attribute 'CurrentMetaMode' (lilicorp:1.0): id=50, switchable=no, source=RandR :: DPY-4: nvidia-auto-select @3840x2160 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=3840x2160, ViewPortOut=3840x2160+0+0}, DPY-1: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +3840+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0}
```

This displays the `CurrentMetaMode` value and this is where I added the `ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On` option to both displays. Note that `DPY-4` is my built-in laptop display, whereas `DPY-1` is the external monitor.

The actual string that needs to be configured is the one after `::` in the output of that command.

```
$ nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DPY-4: nvidia-auto-select @3840x2160 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=3840x2160, ViewPortOut=3840x2160+0+0, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}, DPY-1: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1200 +3840+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1200, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
```

After this, I ran:

```
$ xrandr --output DP-1 --scale=2x2
```

Finally, the external display resolution was fine with no scrolling or any other issues.

Note that after running those commands, the `CurrentMetaMode` is a bit different from what was assigned, probably due to the scaling getting applied:

```
$ nvidia-settings -q CurrentMetaMode

  Attribute 'CurrentMetaMode' (lilicorp:1.0): id=50, switchable=no, source=RandR :: DPY-4: nvidia-auto-select @3840x2160 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=3840x2160, ViewPortOut=3840x2160+0+0, ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}, DPY-1: nvidia-auto-select @3840x2400 +3840+0 {Transform=(2.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,2.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000), ViewPortIn=3840x2400, ViewPortOut=1920x1200+0+0, ResamplingMethod=Bilinear, ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}
```

Hope this solves the problem for someone else too!

Comment: For me `nvidia-settings -q CurrentMetaMode` returns `Attribute 'CurrentMetaMode' (zach-dell:1.0): id=50, switchable=yes, source=xconfig :: NULL`

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem. I got it resolved with `--scale 2x2.001`. Oddly enough, `--scale 2x1.999` or `2x2.0001` didn't work, so be sure to try several numbers around 2.

Comment: i had this problem too... brute force worked out for mr

Comment: What did you brute force? Values of 2?

Comment: And how strange! Thanks for the post. I ended up just giving up. I've actually got a second computer now connected via synergy. Works quite well for when I occasionally need windows applications (second computer is win)

Comment: This actually works. Someone should report that... anyway, big thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Milos for your excellent solution, which worked well for me!

I've a small addition. Besides using the command line you can also comfortably set the `ForceFullCompositionPipeline` in the Nvidia-Settings UI. For this you've to go to "X Server Display Configuration", click on "Advanced" and just activate the option "Force Full Composition Pipeline". 
Please see https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLsX4.jpg for an example.

---

PS: I'm using a triple-head setup with two external monitors (1920x1080; 1680x1050) and an internal 3k monitor (3840x2160). For this to work I apply the following xrandr-config:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --auto --output HDMI-0 --auto --scale 2x2 --above eDP-1-1 --output DP-1 --auto --scale 2x2 --rotate left --right-of eDP-1-1
```