# Ubuntu 16.04 Vertical Tearing (NVIDIA with Dual Screens)

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, tearing

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.06 LTS with two 1920x1080 monitors connected (one over HDMI and another over DVI). I have terrible vertical screen tearing on both of the monitors.

There are many helpful videos which address vertical tearing with a single monitor, but none for more than one:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYWer86A20s
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvD9JvEna8o

Solutions are very similar, and involve configuring the NVIDIA settings with the **ForceFullCompositionPipeline** enabled. The following solution works for a **single monitor ONLY**:

```
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

Can anyone suggest how to apply this fix simultaneously to both monitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the steps which worked for me using two screens:

1. Run `xrandr` to reveal the monitor connection names, resolutions and offsets:

> Take note of the following two lines which are needed later

```
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0
```

2. Use the following code as a template to fix screen tearing:

> Replace the screen **names, resolutions and offsets** for each screen as per your configuration:

```
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+1920+0, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
```

3. Add the previous command to the **Startup Application Preferences** to ensure the fix persists across reboots.

Upon running the 2nd step command, your screens may blank to black momentarily before the fix is applied. You might like to [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfL_JkcEFbE) to test whether the tearing has gone.

Credit [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/979551/867437) for the dual screen code which was adapted.

Comment: THANK YOU so much! I had terrible screen tearing on my external monitor. This fixed it for me.