# Display settings are lost on boot after nvidia settings script is applied - Solved

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

After applying the solution on
https://askubuntu.com/a/1179031, to solve my screen tearing issues on my external monitor, every time I boot, my display arrangement settings are lost (join displays goes to mirror, primary monitor selected goes to default).

I use a laptop that has and nvidia gtx 1650, but obviously used only to apply settings on external monitor via HDMI. I should inform that I have used this script once again in a previous installation of ubuntu 20.04 and it was working just fine without any issues. Today I had to format again, installing ubuntu 20.04 and I face this when I try to re-fix my issue.
I've tried many things like saving nvidia settings to xorg but that makes my laptop monitor disappear, I've tried to modify the script myself but I am not experienced at all in issues like these, apparently the command by itself resets the arrangement.

Should I use something else to make a change in settings after the script runs or modify it in any way so that it does not affect the displays arrangement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update to this...
I researched a bit, and while I tried many things like writing xrandr settings script to run on boot etc, I came up with a more simple and not-likely-a-solution.
I accidentally removed my HDMI cable while I was cleaning, and when I plugged it in again, all went back to my normal settings that keep existing between boots
So I'll consider this solved for my situation.